# Rspec NoMethodError: undefined method `call', yet everything works via rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm a rails/rspec newb trying to learn.  I've setup the following data model (excerpt)

```
t.string :foo
t.string :bar
t.date :future_date
```

and I have a web form to create these entries associated with a user, similar to the microposts in this [rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts#top).  The web form looks like this (excerpt):

```
<%= f.label :foo %>
<%= f.text_field :foo %>
<%= f.label :bar %>
<%= f.text_field :bar %>
<%= f.date_select :future_date %>
```

with a button, "Create", that initiates the post.  Everything seems to work fine via rails console; the web form displays correctly, the entries are created correctly, the database is being populated correctly.  However, when I run rspec I get

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `call' for #<RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationTarget:0x0000000492b7c0>
```

Here is the relevant request spec (excerpt):

```
it "should not create a foobar" do
  expect { click_button "Create" }.should_not change(Foobar, :count)
end
```

In other words, click "Create" with no info filled in.  I have a similar example later with info filled in but nearly the same click_button that also throws this error (should change .by(1)).  I have similar click_button tests working fine for the user creation portion (nothing/something entered) which, other than future_date, is very similar.  That, plus something I ran across in my endless googling, leads me to believe the date is somehow to blame, perhaps an inconsistency in versions or something.  Especially since in actual use everything is working fine.  This is with ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.6, and Rspec 2.11.1.  Any insight is very much appreciated.

Comment: try `expect { click_button "Create" }.to_not change(Foobar, :count)`

Comment: That did it.  I went back to my other click button examples and they also have .to and not .should.  Facepalm.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In RSpec >= 2.11 you should use `to` method instead of `should`

```
expect { click_button "Create" }.to_not change(Foobar, :count)
```

Answer (score 2):

That should say...

```
it "should not create a foobar" do
  lambda { click_button "Create" }.should_not change(Foobar, :count)
end
```

... so `lambda`, not `expect`.

Comment: As written this doesn't work but I looked it up and did "lambda do/ click_button "Create"/ end.should_not change(Foobar, :count)" which did work.

Comment: Curly brackets should work the same, so not sure why they didn't. Maybe should not have the space before the opening `{` or something? I'll try to check that out later when at my workstation.

Comment: I agree, but I've run into that problem before.  Version difference maybe?  Or maybe the problem is just me.